# Error initializing YouTube API client: Not a valid origin for the client

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api

The error occurs during the initialization of the YouTube API client, specifically stating: "Not a valid origin for the client." This problem is associated with the client's origin not being recognized or registered for the provided client ID. The origin in question is "https://e4171bb…". I'm seeking guidance on resolving this issue to ensure the proper initialization of the YouTube API client in my web application.
[image]

Here where the error came from:
[image]

Code behind the button:

```js
  async function initiateYouTubeSync() {
        try {
          // Prompt user for YouTube Channel ID
          const channelID = prompt('Please enter your YouTube Channel ID:');

          // Check if the user entered a Channel ID
          if (!channelID) {
            console.error('YouTube Channel ID is required.');
            return;
          }

          // Initialize the YouTube API client
          await gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: 'Placeholder',
            clientId: 'Placeholder',
            discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3'],
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
          });

          // Authenticate user
          const authResult = await gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();

          // Check if authentication was successful
          if (authResult) {
            // Get YouTube channel information
            const channelResponse = await gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
              part: 'snippet,statistics',
              id: channelID,
            });

            const channelData = channelResponse.result.items[0].snippet;
            const channelName = channelData.title;
            const channelDescription = channelData.description;
            const channelProfilePicture = channelData.thumbnails.default.url;

            // Get YouTube video information (example: last uploaded video)
            const videosResponse = await gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
              part: 'snippet',
              channelId: channelID,
              maxResults: 1,
              order: 'date',
            });

            const videoData = videosResponse.result.items[0].snippet;
            const videoTitle = videoData.title;
            const videoDescription = videoData.description;
            const videoThumbnail = videoData.thumbnails.default.url;

            // Get YouTube subscriber count
            const subsResponse = await gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
              part: 'statistics',
              id: channelID,
            });

            const subsCount = subsResponse.result.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;

            // Save the information to your MelliePlay data
            const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            if (user) {
              const email = user.email;

              // Use your Firebase Firestore instance (db) to save the data
              await db.collection('channels').doc(email).set({
                channelName,
                channelDescription,
                channelProfilePicture,
                subsCount,
              });

              await db.collection('videos').doc(email).set({
                videoTitle,
                videoDescription,
                videoThumbnail,
              });

              // Close the popup
              closeSyncPopup();
            } else {
              console.error('User not authenticated.');
            }
          } else {
            console.error('YouTube authentication failed.');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error initiating YouTube synchronization:', error);
        }
      }
```

I attempted to initialize the YouTube API client with the provided API key and client ID. I expected a successful initialization, enabling interaction with the YouTube API. However, the actual result was an error stating, "Not a valid origin for the client," with the origin being "https://e4171bb…". I need assistance in resolving this issue to ensure proper client ID registration and API initialization.

One of my tries:
[image]

how can i fix this?